# Setting CSS to use when printing from JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I am writing a program which needs to print notes about deliveries made. Currently using the JavaFX 8 printing methods I've been able to create a basic delivery note however the default style for displaying a TableView contains a lot of greyscale which makes a physical printed copy look strange and difficult to read.

I have used CSS to style the TableView to be solid black and white however when printing it seems to ignore the CSS that I have set.

Here's what I have currently:

```
private void printDeliveryNote(){
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    PageLayout pageLayout = Printer.getDefaultPrinter().createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
    Group pane = new Group();
    pane.getChildren().addAll(getNodeToPrint());
    pane.getStylesheets().add("css/main.css");

    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(new Stage())){
        boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, pane);
        if (success){
            job.endJob();
        }
    }
}

private Node getNodeToPrint() {
    Group group = new Group();
    Label prntDeliveryId = new Label("Delivery Id: " + txtDeliveryId.getText());
    prntDeliveryId.setLayoutX(txtDeliveryId.getLayoutX());
    prntDeliveryId.setLayoutY(txtDeliveryId.getLayoutY());

    Label prntDate = new Label("Date: " + txtDate.getText());
    prntDate.setLayoutX(txtDate.getLayoutX() - 20);
    prntDate.setLayoutY(txtDate.getLayoutY());

    Label prntTitle = new Label(lblTitle.getText());
    prntTitle.setLayoutX(lblTitle.getLayoutX());
    prntTitle.setLayoutY(lblTitle.getLayoutY());
    prntTitle.setFont(lblTitle.getFont());

    ImageView imgBarcode = new ImageView(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(handleBarcode(txtDeliveryId.getText()), null));
    imgBarcode.setLayoutX(txtDeliveryId.getLayoutX());
    imgBarcode.setLayoutY(txtDeliveryId.getLayoutY());

    TableView<InstrumentContainer> prntInstrumentList = new TableView<InstrumentContainer>();
    setupInstrumentList(prntInstrumentList);
    prntInstrumentList.setLayoutY(lstInstruments.getLayoutY() + 40);
    prntInstrumentList.setPrefWidth(lstInstruments.getPrefWidth());
    System.out.println(prntInstrumentList.getHeight());
    prntInstrumentList.setLayoutX(lstInstruments.getLayoutX());
    group.getChildren().addAll(
            prntDeliveryId,
            prntDate,
            prntInstrumentList,
            prntTitle,
            imgBarcode
    );
    return group;
}
```

The CSS file looks like this (which works when displaying on a form rather than when printed):

```
.table-row-cell{
-fx-table-cell-border-color: #424242;
}
.column-header{
-fx-border-color: #424242;
-fx-background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

The TableView with the style applied to it on the form looks like this:

[image: How it should look]

But when printed it still has the default style:
[image: How it actually looks]

Any ideas of how to style a node which is being printed?

Comment: I wonder whether it's a precedence thing. Try adding `!important` to the declarations e.g. `-fx-border-color: #424242 !important;`

Comment: That actually worked perfectly! Thanks! I've been stuck on this for ages, no idea why I didn't even think of that. Could you add that as an answer so I can mark it as correct? Cheers

Comment: No problem. Yep, I've added a proper answer with a bit more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a precedence issue. JavaFX includes its own default stylesheet [`modena.css`](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470)* which can, and often does, use higher specificity rules than any custom ones you may have added.

One way to get around this would be to add `!important` to each of the declarations:

```
.table-row-cell {
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: #424242 !important;
}
.column-header {
    -fx-border-color: #424242 !important;
    -fx-background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

If you have a lot of properties to override this might become a bit tedious. You could look at the default styles in the default stylesheet (linked above) and use a [specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st) to work out how to make your selector more specific than the default one.

---

`*` Older versions may use different default stylesheets.